# Seeking (Open Source) Mobile GIS app for survey?

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, mobile-gis

I'm going to do an on-site survey for a business area development research. 
Therefore I'll visit all of the biggest business district from a medium-scale city (100,000 population) to check present companies, economic sector, building type, etc. I prepared a survey sheet (like a questionnaire) that I would fill into Excel manually after to proceed with my work in QGIS.

Is there any open source mobile GIS application for smart phones that I could use instead?

I could already prepare or import the survey design in the app and do the survey with my phone and data is directly stored digital in a format to continue work (evaluation, analysis) on the computer after.

It would speed up the whole process a lot and could be used for further researches as well.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the Mergin Maps Input app from Lutra Consulting: https://merginmaps.com

[image]

It synchronises well with your QGIS project and has a cloud service for synchronisation.
Here's a tutorial: https://ocw.un-ihe.org/course/view.php?id=11&section=7

Answer (score 2):

Since you will be using QGIS later on, QField is an option. You can create project in Qgis, prepare points layer with attributes needed for survey, add base layers... 
after survey you only have to update project on your desktop to continue work with data.

Geopaparzzi and GvSig are good options also, simple interface. You would only have to manualy prepare custum forms (https://geopaparazzi.github.io/geopaparazzi/#_using_form_based_notes), app already offers basemap and its easy to import data to QGIS (https://geopaparazzi.github.io/geopaparazzi/#_qgis).

GeoODK is open source as well and will to the job just as good. There is plugin for Qgis as well to create forms and manage data but not for QGIS 3 yet (https://opendatakit.org/2017/05/connect-qgis-layers-and-odk-forms-with-qgisodk/)

There are probaby more options, decision on what to use is on you. I suggest you google some videos on each to see what interface for filling questionnaire suits you the most.

Comment: I have used geopaparazzi and found it to be feature rich. I did have one problem, my Sony tablet corrupted the database on the device so I lost most of my data after a fieldwork campaign. This issue did not occur on Android phones. After taking to developer using Android air seemed to be a more reliable method of getting data of the device. That's my top tip!

Comment: Thanks for the answers! As mentioned, I will use QGIS 2.18 to evaluate and analyze survey data later. We already got the all layers needed, one point layer (in this case housenumbers) will be the reference. I will prepare the survey form on QGIS desktop and then simply edit the layer in the field. Therefore Q Field seems more than suitable. Other options I consider are geopaparazzi and NextGIS. But for now I will focus on Q Field and do a test...